# Реализация многослойного слайдера экранов на ViewPager2

Tags: android, kotlin

На экране активности требуется расположить несколько фрагментов (около 12), между которыми можно слайдить по горизонтали. При этом, достигнув определенных фрагментов, слайдить можно еще и по вертикали, к другим слайдам. Получается примерно такая схема: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С созданием горизонтального слайда проблем не возникает, но как добавить побочные слайды? Реализуемо ли это?

Answer (score 0):

Для реализации горизонтального слайда можно использовать ViewPager2 и его адаптер. Для добавления побочных слайдов можно в каждом фрагменте, который слайдит по вертикали, использовать вложенный ViewPager2 со своим адаптером. Таким образом, можно добиться необходимой функциональности и слайдить как по горизонтали, так и по вертикали.